# Filtering with STFT

Tags: fft, filters, filter-design, signal-analysis, stft

I have sucessfully implemented a STFT (+inverseSTFT with perfect reconstruction of original signal, with overlap add, etc.) in order to work on audio files.

Using this STFT / iSTFT framework, I have tested :

- Basic "noise reduction" algorithm that works by spectral subtraction of a noise template -> it works very well !
- Hi-pass filtering by zeroing the lowest bins (or, better idea : multiplying these lowest bins by a smooth window, like Hann).  It works (the filtering is good to my ears), but the spectrogram is not what I want :

[image]

I would prefer (for the low frequency 0hz-300hz) something like :

[image]

**What should I do in the STFT array in order to do a good hi-pass filtering?** (i.e. having a clean spectrogram in the low frequencies like the second picture here)

PS : here is the STFT scheme I use in Python :  http://pastebin.com/MdycVLQk

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do filtering of noise in the Time-Frequency domain, (STFT/iSTFT framework), and not just use a simple filter? If you can work with the original audio file, you can use efficient filtering techniques. If you are forced to remove more complicated noises, then you can work in the TF-domain with STFT/iSTFT non-linear methods. Which one suits you best?

Comment: I use STFT/iSTFT in order to do Noise reduction (I use a "noise template", and then I can do spectral subtraction in the STFT framework). This is a very classical topic, and at the end, OLA is used to reconstruct the signal. It works.
BUT I also want to hi-pass the signal, and so I wondered if it was possible to do this hi-pass filtering in the STFT framework (if possible, I'd want to use the STFT framework as much as possible in order to avoid lots of totally different processings!)

Comment: Ok I see. In your 'noise template', you mean that you are given what the shape of your noise will look like in the (modulus) of Time-Frequency domain?

Comment: Yes. I use a part of the sound where there is "Noise only" and then I compute its STFT. I do averaging along frames, and I get an average "modulus" for each bin : this is the *noise floor*.   Then I do some sort of **subtraction** of this noise floor to the signal I want to denoise. Read for example Ephraim Malah algorithms, etc.

Comment: Ok, then in this case, and for more complicated noises in the Time-Frequency domain, yes you can use STFT/iSTFT with OLA reconstruction, or LSE reconstruction. OLA reconstruction of an STFT is actually a heuristic, but can still be used. The LSE has a firmer theoretical basis. Both can work however. Also note that the OLA in time-domain convolution is NOT the same as what is meant in your OLA of the iSTFT. They are very different. All in all, sounds good. I wanted to understand why you were doing it in the STFT/iSTFT domain and not time domain, and your reason is very good.

Answer (score 3):

The techniques you are referring to advanced techniques, and are generally known as "Denoising via STFT-masking".

First, you create an STFT matrix, and mask its modulus (that is, the absolute magnitude of the STFT matrix) by whatever weights you chose. You can pick binary masks, (null out Time-Frequency bins you do not want while retaining Time-Frequency bins you do want), or you can perform soft-masking, in which the weights are not binary, but follow some metric commensurate with your data in the Time-Frequency plane.

Next, you apply an inverse STFT, and this can be done by finding the Least Squares Estimate of a time-domain signal, that would give the modified (complex) STFT after you have performed the masking. (See this paper [here](http://recherche.ircam.fr/anasyn/roebel/amt_audiosignale/VL2.pdf) and [Equation 6 of Griffin and Lin](http://musicweb.ucsd.edu/~sdubnov/catbox/Reader/GriffinLimMSTFT.pdf) for a Least-Squares treatment of inverse STFT transforms via Time-Frequency bin nulling). (In your STFT inversion, you must also make sure that the sum of the window co-efficients across summed frames add up to unity, so often times half cycle sin window is used with 50% overlap in the STFT analysis. This is not the only solution however).

Therefore in its simplest incarnation, filtering out high-frequency components in the STFT domain means simply setting those STFT bins to zero, and then applying the Least-Squares Optimization algorithm to re-synthesizing your time-domain vector. (Similarly, if you want to do a high *pass*, you can null out, or softly change, the STFT coefficients  in the low bands of the matrix). Note that the LSE will be intrinsic to the ISTFT if you use the Griffin paper.

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I use : STFT, then modify some values (you're right : only *the modulus* of some values) in the matrix, and then inverse STFT (with a simple Overlap-Add  method : I use a window such that the shifted windows add up to unity).  
I don't understand why is LSE needed for inverse STFT. The inverse can be done without LSE but rather with a simple overlap-add, so why is it interesting to use LSE ?

Comment: @Basj The LSE - (or any other norm for that matter) optimization is required, because an arbitrary STFT is not necessarily a *valid* STFT, in the sense that there is no signal whose STFT is given by what is presented.

Comment: I don't understand : if I have perfect reconstruction with my inverse STFT, then this means that my STFT is valid, don't you think so ? 
Here it is : http://pastebin.com/MdycVLQk

Comment: @Basj Yes, if you do not modify your STFT, then it is a valid STFT, and maps to a given signal. Only if you *modify* your STFT, then there is no guarantee that it remains valid, and LSE or other criteria are then used to estimate what signal might have given rise to your signal.

Comment: Ok I see... What is the definition of *valid* then ? Do you think this one http://pastebin.com/MdycVLQk will produce valid STFT ?

Comment: @Basj The validity simply means that there does exist some finite length signal, that when STFT'd, will yield the STFT modulus that matches your *arbitrary* STFT. I do not know about the code you have presented, but if you follow the Griffin paper, it goes over valid ISTFT methods. The LSE is just one criterion.

Comment: @Basj: The perfect reconstruction with your STFT + inverse STFT is only because the impulse response of your modification filter (none) is very short (1 sample long).

Answer (score 2):

You need to analyze the impulse response of your frequency domain modifications (treat it as a filter), and make sure the length of your overlap (using overlap save/add) is at least as long as the significant portion of this impulse response (above your desired noise level).  This may require a longer FFT, or a frequency domain modification with wider "softer" transition-bands (or both).

Comment: Thanks for answer. As already pointed by Jazzmaniac, it seems that I should zero pad.... But where should I zero pad? Do you could show me the line where I should add zero padding here : http://pastebin.com/MdycVLQk ?

More generally, it seems that I would need to read a good reference about : how to avoid circular convolution and have linear convolution (is *this* the point here?). Do you have a book reference for this ?

Comment: Instead of zero-padding, try a much longer FFT (and IFFT for your fast convolution result) with much more overlap in your overlap add/save filter.

Comment: Where a longer FFT (pastebin.com/MdycVLQk) ? I'm still a bit lost ;)

Comment: I've never understood why people still bother with this  stuff. [It's close to useless.](http://espace.library.uq.edu.au/view/UQ:10657)

Comment: Hi @PeterK, which stuff are you talking about : using a zero-padded STFT / iSTFT ? Or even using STFT filtering ?
I recall that I want to do STFT hipass-filtering just because I already have a STFT/iSTFT framework in my processing chain (for Noise reduction), so I would like to *re-use* it while filtering...

Comment: STFT "filtering".  Any problem you can define can be better solved using different techniques for cheaper computational cost. It's just a waste of time and energy. IMO. YMMV. Objects in the mirror are closer than they appear. :-)

Comment: @PeterK. I have saved your paper since it sounds like an interesting read. :-) I think TF-filtering can be useful in select cases, but I agree that it needs to be justified. I have used TF-filtering for a number of cases (blind denoising). I will be happy to discuss. What is the best way to reach you?

Comment: @user4619: We can discuss in the chat room here, or we can find some way to exchange email addresses.

Comment: @PeterK. Email I found on your CV ok?

Comment: @user4619 Should be!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just multiply the STFT frames with your filter response and invert the fourier transform to get a filtered signal. Any multiplication in frequency domain is a convolution in time domain. And the frequency response you use has a certain time domain kernel associated with it. This kernel will wrap around at the two frame boundaries when you convolve like that, because FFT convolution is inherently circular. Specifically steep filters like your high pass will have a rather long range effect on samples and introduce the artifacts you're seeing.

The solution is to use overlap add or overlap save convolution schemes that turn the circular convolution into linear convolution.

Comment: You can in fact multiply STFT bins with whatever co-efficients you like and then inverse transform, provided that the resulting gibbs phenomena is either acceptable or negligible. LSE techniques exist to mitigate its effects. This is an advanced field known as Time-Frequency Masking. See my answer for some links.

Comment: What do you mean by using an overlap add scheme that turn circ conv into linear conv?

Here is the STFT scheme I use : http://pastebin.com/MdycVLQk
(simplified, note that the 3 or 4 first frames won't be perfectly reconstructed, but this can easily be solved with a longer code)

Comment: @user4619, I disagree. What you propose is not suitable for the task at hands. The OP obviously wants to realize a time frequency filter and that implies a convolution. Of course you can first make an error and then try to cover it up by trying to minimize it afterwards, but that really misses the points and makes thing much more complicated than necessary. If you want real time frequency filtering you wouldn't need that either. The theory of Weyl symbols already does that without the need to use any kind of fitting or other approximate solutions.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac This is question in the STFT/iSTFT framework. It is not a question in the time-domain only, (where you can use convolution as you suggested), or wavelet domain, (where you would not need LSE). Thus the answer is also in the STFT/iSTFT framework. Time-Frequency masking is a valid technique, but no one is saying it is the only technique.

Comment: Thanks @Jazzmaniac, do you have an idea on how to modify my algorithm (http://pastebin.com/MdycVLQk) in order to have what you're talking about (ie linear conv instead of circular)

Comment: @user4619, my proposal works with time varying kernels just fine. You calculate one kernel per frame. That's the best you can achieve with other methods based on the time frequency trade off as well.

Comment: @Basj, you just have to pad your STFT frame with zeros, on both sides of the frame, in time domain. Then you apply the FFT->multiplication->iFFT processing and add the frame sequence up so that the areas that have been padded overlap. Just look for a tutorial for overlap add convolution, it's exactly what you need. You only use a different multiplication vector for each STFT frame.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Once again, more than one way to skin the cat. The question is how to filter in the STFT/iSTFT framework. Otherwise, OP can just say "I want to high pass my signal". Read the question. I am contesting your statement that we "cant" just null out coefficients. This is untrue. One can, and it is done with good fidelity in the optimization framework. You seem to be taking this the wrong way. No need for consternation on your part.

Comment: @user4619, No, you can't just null out the coefficients. Like you explained you have to put a lot of effort into covering up the error that you introduce to the resynthesis if you do just that. And again, my method is not just about time constant filtering, it works for time varying filters without ANY additional effort, you just use a different frequency response for each single frame.

Comment: @user4619, in addition the method you propose is only an approximation and not free of artifacts. But most importantly, it is way too complicated for the OPs needs. Overlap add is very simple and does *exactly* what he asks for.

Comment: Yes I would like to keep overlap-add which is very simple...
@Jazzmaniac, once I will have zeropadded my STFT stuff, how will I be able to do a highpass filtering with STFT then?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Your choice of words is poor. In the STFT/iSTFT framework, you CAN null out co-efficients. That is to say, the universe will not explode if you null out co-efficients. You can also reconstruct your signal, (IN THE STFT/iSTFT FRAMEWORK) if you do so using optimization routines. See the papers to learn more about this.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac If this was the time-domain framework, then yes, you can use good old fashioned convolution, with OLA. But in the STFT/iSTFT framework, and for complicated signals in the T-F domain, your method will fail, because it is too simplistic.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac "The OP obviously wants to realize a time frequency filter and that implies a convolution." This is wrong. A time-frequency *linear* filter implies a convolution. Non-linear time-frequency filters do not imply this. You are arbitrarily placing a linear constraint on the problem, whence the STFT/iSTFT framework can, and is, more liberal about it, and non-linear as well as linear techniques can be used.

Comment: @user4619, I was obviously referring to inverting STFT frames when I said that you cannot null out coefficients. And the using frame based OLA is not too simplistic. I work in this field and I regularly design products that perform TF modifications, and the local convolution method works well for a large class of modifications. Also, your classification in "linear" and "nonlinear" does not make any sense. Any multiplicative operator on the TF plane is necessarily linear. And like I said before, the general case is using Weyl symbols, not convolution.

Comment: @user4619, and Weyl symbols ARE local convolutions, with the only difference of them being frame size independent. If you start with an STFT you have already decided to use a certain TF trade-off, so there is no need to use Weyl symbols because they're too general.

Comment: @Basj, you just multiply the short time fourier transform of your frame with your frequency weights like before. The only difference is the symmetric zero padding and that the frequency axis is therefore interpolated, i.e. you have more frequency samples after you performed the FFT.

Comment: Yes @Jazzmaniac, but this will only give me more precision in frequency (ie more freq bins / interpolation), but this won't delete the lower freq problems showed in the picture in my question when I do hipass with zeroing lower frequency bins.
How should I do this hipass filtering in the STFT framework then?

Comment: @Basj, if you zero pad on both ends of the frame then it DOES solve your problem. The multiplication in frequency domain will smear out the frame in time domain. But since you padded with zeros the smearing does not wrap around at the frame boundaries and you don't get boundary artifacts. You only have to make sure that you include the newly generated non-zero samples when you add up the frames to resynthesize the signal.

Comment: Do you mean that after this zero-padding, I will be able to highpass-filter by simply zeroing bins ?

Comment: @Basj, well you should have a small transition between the zero bins and the remaining signal, because a very steep filter response will generate a very long time domain response. But yes, you will be able to apply your high pass filter, but only if you keep the data in the previously padded signal regions.

Comment: Zeroing bins has as infinitely long (or very long above your noise floor) impulse response, which will require an infinitely (or very) long FFT so as not to wrap circularly and cause ringing-like artifacts.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac "The OP obviously wants to realize a time frequency filter and that implies a convolution". No. As I said, this is only true if you are doing linear filtering. If I work in the log-space of the STFT, and filter there, I am not linear anymore. Bottom line: You *can* null out coefficients, and an entire subfield works in this context known as TF-Masking.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Yes, you can use time-domain convolutions, wavelets, and/or Weyl symbols for local/global convolutions. No one is disputing that. What I am pointing out is that you can null out coefficients and reconstruct without catastrophe, and this allows you much greater flexibility for automatic denoising in more complex problems, where normal and classical methods will fail, or become too cumbersome. That is all.

Comment: @user4619, it doesn't matter if you derive your gains from a log function or anywhere else. A multiplication with a weight in TF domain IS a local convolution. And no matter what you do, your change is always equivalent to a multiplication, because you're not synthesizing new information. Your classification as nonlinear is therefore entirely meaningless. You cannot change frequency content without a convolutional operation happening behind the scene, even if you don't recognize it.

Comment: @user4619 Nulling out coefficients will introduce boundary artifacts. You can minimize them, but not avoid them. If you would avoid them you would also avoid nulling out the coefficient effectively. It's as simple as that, because a single coefficient in a STFT frame belongs to a non-localized basis function that does not respect frame locality.

Comment: And just for the record, I would appreciate if you quoted me correctly @user4619. I said "You cannot just multiply the STFT frames with your filter response and invert the fourier transform to get a filtered signal", and note specifically that I spoke about simply "inverting the fourier transform" after modification which introduces a circular convolution, if you want it or not. Denying this only demonstrates lack of understanding.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Let me rephrase to make it clear: If you take an STFT, and filter in that domain, that does not necessarily mean you can convert that into an equivalent global time-domain convolution. That is the point. Example: Take an |STFT|. Perform a median filtering operation on the matrix. Graft back its phase, and inverse transform. Are you really telling me that this can actually be done via a global convolution in the time-domain?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac About the nulling: Yes, they do introduce boundary artifacts, because yes, we are dealing with non-local basis functions such as fourier. (Wavelets work around this issue by having local and finite support). I know this, and I am sure you know this. The point (again), is that it can nevertheless be done, because practically, it can be cheaper to null out coefficients, and inverse transform, rather than computing the exact value to multiply them by, so as to minimize artifacts. That is the point of the approximation. You are making a blanket statement about practicalities.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac As a final note, I think you just took my tone in a negative light from the beginning, which is unfortunate. Even if you forced it to be circular convolution, yes you get artifacts, but also maybe this is acceptable, hence my comment. That was the long and short of it, nothing more. Good day to you.

Comment: @user4619, I don't know where you are taking the claim from that local TF modifications are global time domain convolutions. I never said that. I just said that local multiplications are local convolutions. A local convolution is just a general way to say that the signal is affected locally by adding delayed copies of local parts of the signal. That does in no way imply a global process and specifically not a global convolution. And yes, I took your statement negatively, because you made it very clear that you think my answer was wrong in this aspect. Good day to you too sir

Comment: @Jazzmaniac I never claimed your answer is wrong. If I did I would have downvoted it from the beginning, which was not the case. I simply pointed out the utility of coefficient nulling and it has become a storm in a teacup.